# How do I detect unused macro definitions & typedefs?

Tags: c++, c

It's easy to get a list unused functions and variables with linker feedback, but how can I detect those unused macro definitions & typedefs? Do I have to browse the code line by line and git grep in the whole project?

Comment: The *compiler* can't because it runs after the preprocessor.

Comment: I suppose a solution other than browsing code and grepping would be to run `gcc -E` with a given macro and without a given macro, then compare the results. If they're the same, the macro was unused in the code. There's probably a much better way to do it, though.

Comment: @EricFinn, That doesn't sound so bad to me at first thought. I know that isn't feasible for large code bases, though.

Comment: Tricky. Some macro's might be defined only if built in some specific configuration. E.g. `_WIN_VER` might be set only when targetting Windows.

Answer (score 16):

For macros defined in source files you might try `-Wunused-macros` gcc/clang flag.
There's also `-Wunused-local-typedefs` in gcc.

Answer (score 7):

Static analysis tools for C and C++ programs may include a check on unused preprocessor macros.

For instance see [PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/pcl.htm).

Another possibility would be to go into specific include files and use `#ifdef 0` to remove large sections of macros and then review the compiler errors using a kind of divide and conquer algorithm.

However I would expect that a static analysis tool would be much better approach as the source code size becomes large.

Comment: PC-Lint is a great tool that should be in *every* professional developer's computer.

Comment: Except for those millions of developers that never touch Windoze.

Comment: Flexlint is an alternative to PC-Lint.

Answer (score 2):

For unused macros, you might want to take a look at [coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php).  It has options that might assist with this task.  From the [about page](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=about):

> What symbols would appear within active preprocessor directives under a given configuration?
>
> (A preprocessor directive is active if it is not within the scope of any false #if). Supposing again that you are interested in the C-source in app, you can display a list of these symbols, with file names and line numbers, with the command:
>
> $>coan symbols --recurse --locate --active --once --filter c,h app

It has options to remove conditioned out chunks of code (`#if 0` and friends), and many other useful features for dealing with the C preprocessor.  I would use it to collect all the `#define`d symbols and all the `#ifdef` or `defined` symbols and friends.  I'd sort and uniq those two collections of symbols and diff them.  This is a pretty good way of locating typos.  Then I'd take a histogram of them separately and start with the least frequent and work my way up the lists.

For unused typedefs, that's another challenge.  You could use a cross-reference type program like [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) or [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/), but that's not very automatic.

Answer (score 1):

There is cscout (now open source) at :

https://github.com/dspinellis/cscout

that finds unused 'extern', #define.